# 'Nudging' overset characters downwards

Tags: symbols, amsmath, accents

I am trying to make a vector-like symbol to use in a paper I'm writing.  I am actually able to make almost exactly what I want in Mathematica, in which it looks like this:

[image]

In TeX I am using  `$\overset{\rightharpoonup}{\Gamma_{\! G}}$`, which yields:

[image]

The harpoon on top is set too high.

Also, the high harpoon makes problems with line spacing, which should be evident from the following image:

[image]

How do I "nudge" the `\rightharpoonup` down so it isn't set so high above the `\Gamma`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Adjust the -0.75ex to taste
\newcommand{\tightoverset}[2]{%
  \mathop{#2}\limits^{\vbox to -.5ex{\kern-0.75ex\hbox{$#1$}\vss}}}

% Just for fun, a tikz solution
\newcommand{\tikzoverset}[2]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(X.base),inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]{%
    \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (X) {$#2$}; 
    \node[yshift=1pt] at (X.north) {$#1$};
}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
$\overset{\rightharpoonup}{\Gamma_{\!G}}$
$\tightoverset{\rightharpoonup}{\Gamma_{\!G}}$
$\tikzoverset{\rightharpoonup}{\Gamma_{\!G}}$
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

(This will also give you a larger harpoon, which is closer to your Mathematica example.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Of all the answers, your tikz overset worked the best.

Answer (score 12):

You can reduce the height using `\smash` and insert a fake height to move the accent up/down:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}

$\overset{\rightharpoonup}{\Gamma_{\!G}}\ 
   \overset{\rightharpoonup}{\vphantom{a}\smash{\Gamma_{\!G}}}$

\end{document}
```

`\vphantom{a}` is just to insert an object of height `a` (no ascenders). Alternatively, you could use `\rule{0pt}{.6ex}`, say.

Answer (score 11):

You may want to consider using the `\overrightharp` command that's provided by the `harpoon` package. The symbol's overall length adapts automatically to the width of its argument.

Note that unlike most math-accent symbols, the `\overrightharp` macro operates in *text* mode. If it's going to be used regularly in math contexts, it's probably a good idea to create a wrapper macro, say `\orh`, that operates correctly while in math mode. The following MWE shows how this might be done:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{harpoon,amsmath}
\newcommand*{\orh}[1]{\text{\overrightharp{\ensuremath{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\overrightharp{$\Gamma_{\!G}$} and $\orh{\Gamma_{\!G}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Separately, if the term `\Gamma_{\!G}` is going to be used frequently in your document, you may want to create a dedicated macro, say `\def\GG{\Gamma_{\!G}}`. This will save you you a lot of typing (and avoid lots of opportunities for creating typos...) in the document itself.

Answer (score 3):

It is my understanding that the “correct” method for these kinds of things is a mathematical accent. With XeTeX, the underlying definition could then be, for example (would need to have the fonts set up prior to this):

```
\def\rharp{\XeTeXmathaccent"7"0"20D1 } % for luatex: \Umathaccent
$ \rharp\Gamma \qquad \rharp{\Gamma_G} \qquad \rharp{\Gamma_{GG}} $
```

which looks like (with XITS Math active): 
[image]

The `unicode-math` -package has this mathematical accent accessible with the command:

```
\rightharpoonaccent
```